# Cancel New CoreData Object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

In my app, I have my master view controller which displays all my coredata objects.

When the user adds an object this runs and the next detail view opens to enter details for the new object:

```
-(IBAction)addPerson:(id)sender
{
    Person *p = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    PersonDetailViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PersonDetail"];
    vc.managedObjectContext = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext;
    vc.person = p;
    vc.isNewPerson = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Now I have a delete button in the detail view which calls this:

```
[managedObjectContext deleteObject:person];
    NSError *err;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&err])
    {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", err, [err userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
```

This is how I currently cancel a new coredata object. However I am having issues with it.

How would you recommend I best cancel the creation of a new object? Create and delete, or never create it until confirmed? I'm unsure.

Comment: *"However I am having issues with it."* - What are the issues?

Comment: Hmm, I've narrowed it down to a rather strange point. If I click the cancel button normally its fine, the object is removed as if it was never added. However, if I click cancel while still editing the text field (keyboard present) it returns to the master view with the object visible, selecting the object and making changes crashes the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd actually never create the managed object until confirmed!

But in the first place I'd rewrite the `PersonDetailViewController` to not have a dependency to the `Person` entity at all (loose coupling). Instead I'd define properties in your `PersonDetailViewController` for the various attributes of the `Person` object you like to set/edit and then handle the creation of the `Person` managed object in a save delegate method or so. With this approach you could also cancel the creation use-case half through, without the need for creation of a new managed object etc.

For better illustration, the delegate method would look somewhat like this:

```
- (void) personDidSave: (PersonDetailViewController*) controller {
        // Create a new Person object with the values from the controller
        // and add persist it to core data
        Person *p = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        p.name = controller.name;
        p.surname= controller.surname; 
        // etc.

        // save to core data

        // Refresh the table or whatever view
    }
```

Comment: Ok good idea. But how come I can't just store the details like first and last name in a `Person` object which I haven't inserted into my entity? When I do it still acts as though I've interested the object.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand to 100% what you mean, but your solution is absolutely valid too! My approach just propagates the loose coupling principle a bit more. You could then use the PersonDetailViewController independently from the Person class etc.